# running webdriver from vagrant in my local machine

Tags: django, selenium, vagrant-windows, django-tests, pytest-django

I am running vagrant on windows machine, using "ubuntu/trusty64" box.
I running selenium tests on vagrant (using pytest-selenium with django)
how can I set the webdriver work with my local machine(windows) firefox/chrome ?

did it possible to trigger my local browser from vagrant machine ?
did i need X-server for it ?

Comment: Do you specifically want to test Firefox/Chrome on Windows? If not, it might be easier to use [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) instead.

Comment: Yes, I want to be able to run Firefox/Chrome on Windows.

Comment: In that case, I think you'll have to install selenium server on Windows, then use the remote Web driver in your script.